# Django WebSocket no respsone and page is always white

Tags: python, django

I runserver the websocket and get

> **You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth,
>   contenttypes, sessions. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
>   September 06, 2017 - 04:02:26 Django version 1.10.5, using settings
>   'untitled.settings' Starting Channels development server at
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Channel layer default
>   (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer) Quit the server with CONTROL-C.**

I click that url and the only thing I get 
[white and on response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCqlF.png)

My server is still same like above , nothing change.

Thanks for your help.

here is my code

***setting.py***

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 8000)],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'example_channels.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

***example_channels/example/consumers.py:***

```
from channels import Group


def ws_connect(message):
    Group('users').add(message.reply_channel)


def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group('users').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

***example_channels/routing.py***

```
from channels.routing import route
from example.consumers import ws_connect, ws_disconnect


channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect),
    route('websocket.disconnect', ws_disconnect),
]
```

***_base.htm***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Example Channels</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </div>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  {% block script %}{% endblock script %}
</body>
</html>
```

***user_list.html***

```
{% extends 'example/_base.html' %}

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
  <script>
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/users/');

    socket.onopen = function open() {
      console.log('WebSockets connection created.');
    };

    if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
      socket.onopen();
    }
  </script>
{% endblock script %}
```

***example_channels/example/views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def user_list(request):
    return render(request, 'example/user_list.html')
```

***example_channels/example/urls.py:***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from example.views import user_list


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', user_list, name='user_list'),
]
```

***example_channels/example_channels/urls.py:***

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('example.urls', namespace='example')),
]
```

Comment: Your error clearly states to do `python manage.py migrate`, give it a try

Comment: yes , I do it and my console become                                              September 06, 2017 - 15:16:50
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'untitled.settings'
Starting Channels development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.   however , I click url  and is still blank

Answer (score 0):

run this two cmd in terminal to sync database

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: yes , I do it and my console become September 06, 2017 - 15:16:50 Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'untitled.settings' Starting Channels development server at 127.0.0.1:8000 Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer) Quit the server with CONTROL-C. however , I click url and is still blank and no change on console

Answer (score 0):

untill you migrate nothing will get stored in database so it's required to sync the database you can register your app in "Installed apps" in settings.py file

then run

python manage.py  makemigrations

or

```
      python manage.py  makemigrations 'appname'
```

and then run

python manage.py migrate

Comment: yes , I do it and my console become September 06, 2017 - 15:16:50 Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'untitled.settings' Starting Channels development server at 127.0.0.1:8000 Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer) Quit the server with CONTROL-C. however ,  I click url and is still blank and no change on console

Comment: instead of {% enblock content %}  try {% endblock  %}

Comment: yes , I have done this and my page is still blank and nothing happened.

Comment: i don't know much js so can explain what the script is doing

Comment: is title is comming in head ?

Comment: if you connect the websocket , console will print you connect .

Comment: Doesn`t show. The only thing is 未命名 in chinese which mean unnamed in English.

Comment: try {% extends 'example/_base.htm '  %}

Comment: Sorry , there is no file named _base.htm and I just copy wrong code.